# Copy values and border format too

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I want to copy some data from 2 columns ("Nastavit D" sheet, column Q2 to R1000) to the end of the columns with similar data on another sheet ("Chain" sheet, column A1 to B1000). I have a code for this, but I need improvement so that it copies the border formats too. Also, If cell C3 in sheet called "Nedotykat sa!!!" is TRUE, then I want it to copy the data to Sheet called "Chain" BEFORE any other data (basically putting in it A1, "pushing" the existing data there down below the new copied data), instead of putting it to the end. I have a code for copying and putting the data into the end of "Chain" sheet.

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim x, y(), I As Long, ii As Long

    If Sheets("Nastavit D").[Q2] = "" Then Exit Sub
    x = Sheets("Nastavit D").[Q2:R1000]
    For I = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(I, 1) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve y(1 To 2, 1 To I)
            For ii = 1 To 2
                y(ii, I) = x(I, ii)
            Next
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    With Sheets("Chain")
        .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(y, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(y)
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
I started to rewrite the whole VBA code based on suggestions by @BigBen and @Jeff. However, for now, it copies the whole range of Q2:R1000, even blank cells, because they contain formulas I think. How can I copy only cells with actual values, even if it contains formulas?

```
Sub CopyRangeUpdated()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("Chain").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Sheets("Nastavit D").[Q2] = "" Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("Nastavit D").Range("Q2:R1000").Copy
  Sheets("Chain").Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True
'clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to copy borders, then use the clipboard and copy/pastespecial, instead of your current array approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for @BigBen's suggestion

**Edited in response to question edit**

The skip blanks not compress what is copied to remove blanks, it will just "skip over" them. for example:

1 A

_ B

3 C

pasting col1 onto col2 will result in:

1

B

3

```
'copy range
Sheets("Nastavit D").Range("Q2:R1000").Copy

'paste values
Sheets("Chain").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False 

 'copy formatting
 Sheets("Nastavit D").Range("Q2:R1000").Copy 

'paste formatting
Sheets("Chain").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

To "push data down", I would insert cells beforehand:

```
Sheets("Chain").Rows("2:1001").insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Then delete blank rows with something like this (the i is there to prevent an infinite loop if the last row is blank)

```
i=2
for x = 2 to 1001
    if i<10001 then
        if sheet("Chain").Range("A"&x).text = "" then
            Sheet("Chain").Range("A"&x).entirerow.delete xlshiftup

            'if say row2 is deleted, need to re-check row2 new value
            x = x-1
        end if
    else
        exit for
    end if
    i=i+1
next x
```